# JHipster new module : cannot add translation

Tags: jhipster

I have added a new module with several components inside JHipster. I would like so add the translation in the html part with the JHipsterTraslationService and tried to do it but I do not know. I think I have to suscribe to the new service but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Jhipster use jhiTranslate in the html, for example: `<label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="myApp.myComponent.myWelcome">My default welcome text</label>`, 
this refers to the value of the field in your translation .json file, it will look for it in that file and replace it with the value it has. Otherwise, it will show the value, `"My default welcome text"`.

When you create a component with jhipster using angular cli, the translation files are created in each language folder of your application.`(example: myApplicationName\src\main\webapp\i18n\en)`

This is the example they put in their documentation ([Generating Components, Directives, Pipes and Services](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/)) for create components:

```
ng generate component my-new-component
ng g component my-new-component # using the alias

# Components support relative path generation
# Go to src/app/feature/ and run
ng g component new-cmp
# your component will be generated in src/app/feature/new-cmp
# but if you were to run
ng g component ../newer-cmp
# your component will be generated in src/app/newer-cmp
```

I believe that it is easy and better to use this method of creation, because it will create all the necessary files, be it a component, service, directive, route, etc.

Additionally, if you have already created the components, you will have to manually create each .json file in its corresponding folder according to the languages of your application. You can also add another language to your application ([How to add languages after project generation?](https://www.jhipster.tech/installing-new-languages/)).

Other way.... U can try add other language, with the generator. And check that files was added and what change, with this u can know what files or subscriptions can change.

I hope this helps. ;)